# How to plot studentized residuals and fitted values in R using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, outliers

First, I fitted the model from my data in `clean_sales` and passed it on an object `fit_num_var`, but then I had difficulty making it into a plot to visualize the fitted values and the studentized residuals. My code is below:

```
#Outliers 
attach(clean_sales)
fit_num_var <- lm(SalePrice ~ ResidentialUnits + CommercialUnits + 
                  YearBuilt + TotalUnits + LandSquareFeet + GrossSquareFeet)
fit_num_var
ggplot(fit_num_var, aes(x=as.vector(fitted.values), y=as.vector(residuals))) + 
geom_point() + geom_line() + xlab("Fitted Values") + ylab("Studentized Residuals")
```

The error message was:

Error in as.vector(x, mode) : cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'any'

Please let me know how I should fix this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: Hope you have heard of ggResidpanel https://goodekat.github.io/ggResidpanel-tutorial/tutorial.html.

Answer (score 1):

No reproducible example, but try this:

- don't use `attach()`, use the `data=` argument to `lm()` instead (this isn't your actual problem, but is better practice)
- use `fitted(fit_num_var)`, etc.
- you might also be interested in the `augment` function from the `broom` package

```
fit_num_var <- lm(SalePrice ~ ResidentialUnits + CommercialUnits + 
              YearBuilt + TotalUnits + LandSquareFeet + GrossSquareFeet,
   data=clean_sales)
ggplot(fit_num_var, aes(x=fitted(fit_num_var), 
          y=residuals(fit_num_var))) + 
         geom_point() + smooth() + xlab("Fitted Values") + 
                                   ylab("Studentized Residuals")
```

Comment: happy to try to improve this if there is a stated reason for the downvote ...

Comment: I only see a missing bracket here ` y=residuals(fit_num_var))` which could have been  `y=residuals(fit_num_var)))`. Thank you so much for the code.